# TFS: Moving projects to multiple "branches" in a single branch setting

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I'm new to TFS, so forgive me if I misuse some terms.

So in my company, we have a one branch solution: Basically, all "branches" are located under the same place in TFS.
What I need to do, is move some projects from a shared place, to three different branches. Here's a simplified view of how it looks:

```
Root
-branch A
-branch B
-branch C
-Common area
--project to move 1
--project to move 2
```

And I need to move 1 and 2 to A, B and C. I can move the projects to one of the branches, but then what do I do? Maybe I should move them to A, check in, and then "cherry pick" the changeset to the other branches? I'm not sure it would even work. It's also important to keep the history, which I can't do if I simply copy and paste the projects through windows.

Another thing, I'm currently using workspaces as if they were local branches. I create a workspace and map branch A locally, and do the same for B and C. Is that how you're supposed to use workspaces?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up moving it to one branch which is going to be the base for future branches. and for the other branches I copied it without history.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can move projects to A, then you can merge from A to B and C by choosing `Selected changesets`

[image]

If your company uses branches to isolate risk in your codebase, then you should create a separate workspace for each branch you work in. More details about how to optimize your workspace, refer to the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/optimize-your-workspace?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hey, Thanks!
We ended up moving it to one branch which is going to be the base for future branches. and for the other branches I copied it without history. Thanks anyway!